# Change WooCommerce products query to sort randomly

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

So far I've figured out I need to use the following hook to change the WooCommerce products query:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'xxxx_product_query' );
function xxxx_product_query( $q ){

    ...do something here...
}
```

But how do I:

1.make the query sort all products randomly;

2.keep the randomly sorted products in that order for 30 days and then change it again when the 30 days expire;

3.make all products with the custom field "_new" always appear at the beginning of the query (these should not be sorted randomly).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try modifying your query with this $q->set( 'orderby', 'rand' ); Sorry untested. You might need to run this in a Cron job and store the IDs as an array in your database

Answer (score -1):

You can add an extra sorting option to the Default Sorting Order combobox in the WooCommerce settings page under the Products/Display tab by using this code in your functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );

function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

    if ( 'random_list' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
        $args['order'] = '';
        $args['meta_key'] = '';
    }
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );

function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['random_list'] = 'Random';
    return $sortby;
}
```

Why are you using a '_new' custom field?  You can probably just use the time stamp of when the product was added to establish if the product is new or not.